# QGIS expression: when using overlay_nearest sometimes a feature considers itself its nearest neighbour

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression

When using `overlay_nearest` function in the QGIS expression builder, sometimes a feature considers itself as the nearest geometry, and other times not.

To demonstrate, I made a label expression:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        letter='A'
    THEN
        'fid: ' || "fid" || 
        '\nletter: ' || "letter" || 
        '\n\nnearest fid\'s: ' || array_to_string(
                                      overlay_nearest(layer:=@layer, 
                                          expression:=fid, 
                                          filter:=letter='A', 
                                          limit:=2
                                      )
                                  )
    ELSE
        NULL
END
```

I set the feature limit at 2 to show the 2 nearest `fid`s for each feature to show that the true nearest feature is being found second.

The points outlined in red consider themselves their nearest neighbour, the others do not. It happens also with a projected coordinate system, and with various permutations of the `WHEN` clause.

Can anyone explain why this is?

[image]

Example dataset (CRS is WGS84) -- [GeoPackage download link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApiNQH8NeQCWor1jI2WXA0buhYivlg?e=2nHDye) (with label expression pre-loaded)

| WKT | fid | letter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POINT (27.7981358844261 -24.2696491141906) | 1 | A |
| POINT (27.7988424066944 -24.2678611535372) | 2 | A |
| POINT (27.7989643301811 -24.2688320385901) | 3 | B |
| POINT (27.8007927306901 -24.2685965478542) | 4 | B |
| POINT (27.7979157991226 -24.2678537822582) | 5 | B |
| POINT (27.7995823651664 -24.2670624651733) | 6 | A |
| POINT (27.7999025692956 -24.2692146208195) | 7 | B |
| POINT (27.8002376476489 -24.2696982965109) | 9 | A |
| POINT (27.7984109576877 -24.2694592018388) | 10 | A |
| POINT (27.8001260102486 -24.2667596896059) | 11 | B |

Comment: the overlay_nearest function and others, respond badly if used with the same layer, here bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47201

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought it was caused by the way I was filtering. If you want to make an answer, I can accept it.

I was thinking a workaround could be to check the `fid` and if it matches, take the second array element instead of the first. Seems horribly hacky though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `overlay_nearest` function and others, respond badly if used with the same layer.

Here is a bug report: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47201

Comment: Would it help to duplicate the layer and use the duplicated layer (in fact, the same data) for `overlay_nearest` or does that not improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

So far I noticed that the `overlay_nearest` will result in an array, where the same feature will always be at the 0-index position.

Therefore, like in this thread [Drawing 10 nearest lines from each point connecting to the centroid of the 5 points nearest to each point with QGIS expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/473176/drawing-10-nearest-lines-from-each-point-connecting-to-the-centroid-of-the-5-poi/473228#473228), I am simply suggesting to delete it by its index i.e. 0.

However, in such a case, the number in `limit` should be incremented in one more feature.

```sql
array_remove_at(
    overlay_nearest(
        layer:=@layer,
        expression:=fid, 
        filter:=letter='A', 
        limit:=3 -- notice this change
        )
    0)
```

Comment: The problem was, at the time of posting the question, that the nearest feature was only sometimes itself, and sometimes not. I haven't tried to reproduce the problem recently, but if you're getting consistent results then perhaps there has been a bug fix.

Comment: I got you. Currently, my results are consistent. Perhaps, there was some bug or issue with data etc., it needs investigation